# Server-side resource file loading

Tags: javascript, css, django, design-patterns

Is this an anti-pattern?

For JavaScript and/or CSS code that is repeated between two template files in a Django project, we put that code into a common resource. That resource can then be loaded by a separate request from the client (as is the case with static .js and .css files) or placed in a template file and loaded into the templates that use it server-side, thus avoiding the extra requests that result from creating additional .js or .css files (or increasing the size of existing .js or .css files).

Current practice where I work prefers that latter approach, while I prefer the former. I see the following problems with loading template files on the server side instead of creating additional static files or adding to existing static files:

- The number of requests we avoid by loading resource files on the server is insignificant due to caching.
- The size of the templates is increased with code that could be cached, meaning that more data is sent over the wire.
- This practice spreads CSS and JavaScript code across the project in files that are marked as html templates in spite of their complete lack of actual html text.
- When the common code becomes commonly used in more than two pages on our site, we may need to create additional static files (or add to existing ones) anyway.
- It is generally a good practice to keep JavaScript separated from the DOM; server-loaded resource files don't do much to encourage this practice.

So, is this an anti-pattern we should avoid, or is it a best practice, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents on the issue
Performance wise:
If the JS is important for your landing page rendering, inline it as template.
Otherwise I would generally vote for your way (external JS file) maybe using async, and of course putting the link at the end of the page.
But it some cases like small size scripts, the inline approach can make sense.